# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.-Powerpoint file Open

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, interop, office-automation

I am trying to open the Microsoft PowerPoint File in my ASP.NET Web API but it constantly throwing an exception:

> "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program."

The version of IIS where i have deployed this code is 8.5, which is my production server running on windows server 2012 R2.

However this is not the issue in my development environment it works fine.

Developer Machine Configs:
Windows 7-IIS 7.5

The snippet of the code that fails is included below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = 
    ppApp.Presentations.Open(mappingPptPath,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft doesn't support using Office Automation in this manner, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468057/2912011).

I've experienced the same issue and got around it by using the solution referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370770/2912011) answer. This is really just dodging the problem though, by just using a different library([Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)). In my instance, this worked fine, but I think it all depends on what your trying to do. Open XML may not support "all" features of PowerPoint.

I'm not sure there are any other alternatives to Open XML, this is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598855/generate-power-point-documents-wrapper-dll).